# How to create cox proportional chart in R plotly package

Tags: r, visualization, plotly, cox-regression

I have created a cox proportion plot using ggsurvfit function. Using autoplot package, i convert it into a ggplot chart. Upon applying ggplotly function on it does not work. Says does not support such functions.

Please help

Comment: any chance you could share the code used?

Comment: A minimal working example will come a long way.